# Package DBMS_REDEFINITION missing from Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, dbms-redefinition

I'm trying to partition an existing table in Oracle and the research I've done seems to say that using the [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/html/B14258_02/d_redefi.htm) package seems to be the best way to do this.

The problem is I doesn't seem like my DB has this package.  I'm using Oracle 11g, but the online docs suggest it's been supported since 10.2.

Does anyone know how I can download or otherwise gain access to this package?

Thanks!

Comment: It should just be there. Does your user have the `EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE`? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm#i1006801

Comment: How do I check to see if I have that role?

Comment: Why do you think that you don't have this package?

Answer (score 1):

[Privileges Required for the DBMS_REDEFINITION Package 11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11678)

You do not need that role, that is just an example. I would not use that role, as it grants execute privileges on a lot of other packages as well.

You need the following privileges:

```
grant execute on dbms_redefiniton to your_user;
grant create table to your_user;
grant create materialized view to your_user;
grant create trigger to your_user;
```

The above is enough, if you want to redefine tables in your own schema. If you want to redefine tables in other schemas, you will need the `"ANY"` privileges listed below:

```
CREATE ANY TABLE
ALTER ANY TABLE
DROP ANY TABLE
LOCK ANY TABLE
SELECT ANY TABLE
CREATE ANY TRIGGER
CREATE ANY INDEX
```